# Python регулярные выражения

Tags: python

Мой скрипт делает запрос на сайт, выглядит он вот так:[image: сайт]

Моя регулярка выглядит вот так:

```
string = re.search(r'\d\.\d{8}', str(try_response.content))
```

Но вся проблема в том, что мне нужно найти число, которое находится после текста "Текущее значение этого адреса - *число* BTC", а находится естественно самое первое число (На скрине оно такое же как и в конце, но оно может отличаться)

Я пытался сделать вот таким образом:

```
string = re.search(r'Текущее значение этого адреса - (\d+\.\d{8}) BTC', str(response.content))
```

И по итогу мне выдавало ошибку

Вопрос следующий: как правильно получить это число с помощью регулярных выражений? Буду премного благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re.search в таком варианте, как у Вас, будет выдавать match-объект. Можно преобразовать регулярку к виду:

```
re.search('Текущее значение этого адреса - (\d+\.\d+) BTC', text).group(1)
```

или сделать на re.findall:

```
re.findall('Текущее значение этого адреса - (\d+\.\d+) BTC', text)
```

Тогда будете иметь список с искомым значением.

В остальных случаях надо смотреть, что в response лежит.